# Rails Jquery chained selects

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to setup a jquery chained select when a create a new product

1. Gender
2. Category
3. Subcategory

the gender and category is chaining, minus the subcategory that dont appear!

please someone could give some light? thank's

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var $gender, $category;

    $gender = $('input[id^="product_gender_id"]');
    $category = $('#product_category_id');


    //radio only can response to 'click' event, rather than select event you wrote before.
    $gender.click(function () {

        var gender = $('input[id^="product_gender_id"]:checked').val();

        if (gender == 1); 
        else if (gender == 2); 

        jQuery.get('/products/update_category_select/' + gender, function(data){
            $("#productCategories").html(data);
        })
    });


    $category.change(function() {
        // make a POST call and replace the content

        var category = $('select#product_category_id :selected').val();

        if(category == "") category="0";
        jQuery.get('/products/update_subcategory_select/' + category, function(data){
            $("#productSubcategories").html(data);
        })
        return false;
    });

 });
```

Comment: I did not understand, I suppose you want to select gender and category but not subcategory, but I don't see selectors

Comment: i'm trying to chain gender category and subcategory, so when i choose gender successfully i can choose category, but not the subcategory.

Comment: what is `data` value in `$("#productSubcategories").html(data);`, your question is because `data` is not what you want?

Comment: yeah this should appear, data is a partial with the subcategory collection

Comment: <div id="productSubcategories">
        <%= render :partial => 'subcategories'  %>
      </div>

Comment: I continue without understanding, if `data` is OK so what's wrong? :p. Check your browser console to see a preview of returned data, check the format should be javascript in plain text, and not formatted html

Comment: that's why i'm post a question, because i have no idea why this is happen!

Comment: anyway thank's for your interest!

Comment: Did you check your browser console?, I had an error like you mentioned, and it was because what I said

Comment: i already checked on firebug and nothing, to be honesty when i select the category the server is not getting the subcategories

Comment: `console.log('/products/update_subcategory_select/' + category)` and go to this URL in your browser, tell me what you see.

Comment: in browser or in console.log?